# How to join two Tables which have no unique ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, unique

I am trying to Left join Table 1 to table 2

```
Table1          Table2  
ID  Data        ID  Data2
1   r           1   q
2   t           1   a
3   z           2   x
1   u           3   c
```

After i have left joined this two Tables i would like get something like this

```
  Table1+2      
ID  Data    Data2
1   r        a
2   t        x
3   z        c
1   u        q
```

and NOT

```
  Table1+2      
ID  Data    Data2
1   r        q
2   t        x
3   z        c
1   u        q
```

and my question is: is there any possibility to tell table 2 that if u have used something for table 1, dont use it and give me next value. do i have to make it im T-SQL or to and new column where i can list if this id exists then write 2 if not 1(Number data). How can i solve this problem?
Ty u in advance.

Comment: You have several answers below which might give you the answer/behavior you want, but the best long term solution might be to fix your schema such that joining the way you want can be done simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's no uniqueness in the ID on both tables, lets add some uniqueness to it.
So it can be used to join on.
The window function [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) can be used for that.

An example solution that gives the expected result:

```
DECLARE @TestTable1 TABLE (ID INT, Data VARCHAR(1));
DECLARE @TestTable2 TABLE (ID INT, Data VARCHAR(1));

INSERT INTO @TestTable1 VALUES (1,'r'),(2,'t'),(3,'z'),(1,'u');         
INSERT INTO @TestTable2 VALUES (1,'q'),(1,'a'),(2,'x'),(3,'c');

select 
 t1.ID, t1.Data,
 t2.Data as Data2
from (
  select ID, Data, 
  row_number() over (partition by ID order by Data) as rn
  from @TestTable1
) t1
left join (
  select ID, Data, 
  row_number() over (partition by ID order by Data) as rn
  from @TestTable2
) t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

**Note:** Because of the LEFT JOIN, this does assume the amount of same ID's in table2 are equal or lower can those on table1. But you can change that to a FULL JOIN if that's not the case.

Returns :

```
ID  Data Data2
1   r    a
1   u    q
2   t    x
3   z    c
```

---

To get the other result could have been achieved in different ways.
This is actually a more common situation.
Where one wants all from Table 1, but only get one value from Table 2 for each record of Table 1.

1) A `top 1 with ties` in combination with a `order by rownumber()`

```
select top 1 with ties 
 t1.ID, t1.Data,
 t2.Data as Data2
from @TestTable1 t1
left join @TestTable2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
order by row_number() over (partition by t1.ID, t1.Data order by t2.Data desc);
```

The `top 1 with ties` will only show those where the `row_number()` = 1

2) Using the row_number in a subquery:

```
select ID, Data, Data2
from (
    select 
     t1.ID, t1.Data,
     t2.Data as Data2,
     row_number() over (partition by t1.ID, t1.Data order by t2.Data desc) as rn
    from @TestTable1 t1
    left join @TestTable2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
) q
where rn = 1;
```

3) just a simple group by and a max :

```
select t1.ID, t1.Data, max(t2.Data) as Data2
from @TestTable1 t1
left join @TestTable2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
group by t1.ID, t1.Data
order by 1,2;
```

All 3 give the same result:

```
ID Data Data2
1  r    q
1  u    q
2  t    x
3  z    c
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID INT, DATA VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ID INT, DATA VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @Table1
VALUES
(1,   'r'),        
(2,   't'),        
(3,   'z'),        
(1,   'u')         

INSERT INTO @Table2
VALUES
(1,   'q'),
(1,   'a'),
(2,   'x'),
(3,   'c')   

SELECT
    A.*,
    B.DATA
FROM
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) RowId FROM @Table1) A INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) RowId FROM @Table2) B ON A.ID = B.ID AND
                                                                                                  A.RowId = B.RowId
```